# How to create a actual view using View in Xamarin.Android Views

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a view Add -> New File -> Views (C#) in Xamarin, but Xamarin didn't generate any XML/XAML Files to define the UI - Where am I supposed to create UI Elements for the View?

This is what I have now,
Code:

```
public class CustomScanView : View
    {
        public CustomScanView (Context context) :
            base (context)
        {
            Initialize ();
        }

        public CustomScanView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
            base (context, attrs)
        {
            Initialize ();
        }

        public CustomScanView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
            base (context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            Initialize ();
        }

        void Initialize ()
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I are saying I understand that you want to create a new form, or view or how you may name it. And also that you would like it to be a XAML page.

In your project go to Add > New Item but this time go to Visual C# > Code and add a Forms Xaml Page.
Now you will get a Xaml page.

To use it in your application go to your App.cs file and replace the code there with something like this:

```
public class App : Application
{
  public App ()
  {
    MainPage = new YourNewPageName(); // Add actual name here
  }
}
```

Or call it somewhere else in the code that you would like. For more on this you can take a look [here on my blog](http://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-from-zero-to-hero-part-1/) where I explain more.

Now, I am assuming a lot for you because there is some information missing in your question, so I hope this helps. Else please add more information and try to be more clear about what you want to do and what you have tried so far.